# What causes errors when restoring postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

I'm trying to backup up an entire postgres database and restore it properly, however I am seeing a list of errors when trying to restore the backup.

I am using pg_dump to create a backup sql file. (I have a .pgpass file for password)

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump -d db-w > backup.sql
```

When I try to restore the database with:

```
sudo -u postgres psql db < backup.sql
```

I get a list of errors like:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table
ERROR:  relation <relation> already exists
ERROR:  trigger <trigger> for relation <relation> already exist
```

I haven't made any changes to the database. I simply performed a backup and restore the backup right after.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are restoring your backup into a non-empty database.

Answer (score 0):

your restoring on an existing database, if you want and sure to replace database with the backup you can use option --clean and --create

> -c, --clean
>             Clean (drop) database objects before recreating them. (This might
>             generate some harmless error messages, if any objects were not
>             present in the destination database.)
>
> -C, --create
>             Create the database before restoring into it. If --clean is also
>             specified, drop and recreate the target database before connecting
>             to it.

Comment: Can I use those flags with the psql command? I get an invalid option error

Comment: @ScrawnySquirrel You need to use pg_restore to use the switches etc. You also need to ensure your back up is of the correct format for pg_restore. See documentation here. https://www.postgresql.org/docs